# Cross-reference to a portion of a figure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In my document there is a "Figure 1" for which I have manually labeled parts "(a)" and "(b)" using the `\put(x,y){(a) Some text description here.}` commands [for both (a) and (b)].

I am using the `\label{label name here}` command inside the caption of "Figure 1" alongside the `\ref{label name here}` to produce the desired effect except for one thing. As it stands, I have in my text

> ... are shown in Figure 1(a).

However, only the "1" is the 'link' and not the "(a)". I realise that I currently do not have the code set up for this effect; this is what I am seeking help on.

Note: I am currently using

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=ForestGreen, linkcolor=Red, urlcolor=Blue}
```

========================

## Edited to provide a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.0in, bottom=1.2in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=ForestGreen, linkcolor=Red, urlcolor=Blue}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text here to talk about the first part of the figure followed by a reference to see Figure \ref{Figure1}(a). Some text here to talk about the second part of the figure followed by a reference to see Figure \ref{Figure1}(b).

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\vspace{0.7in}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(5.5,4.5)
\put(-1,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Figure1Name.eps}}
\put(-1,2.65){\footnotesize{(a) Some text describing the first part.}}
\put(-1,-0.45){\footnotesize{(b)Some text describing the second part.}}
\end{picture}
\parbox{5.4in}{\vspace{0.5in}\caption{\normalsize{The caption for Figure 1 goes here. Both parts of Figure 1 are described. \label{Figure1}}}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

========================

## Output

[image: The file output]

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (MWE) that generates the problem you're encountering and trying to solve. As a general matter, in order to create a hyperlink to an entity named "Figure 1(a)" -- as opposed to, say, "Figure 1" (your current state) -- LaTeX/hyperref needs to be given a `\label` instruction somewhere nearby the subfigure, so that a unique hook can be created. A `\put` statement will *not* generate the required label. Have a look at the `subfigure` and `subcaption` packages for ways to create separate subfloats (which can then be given hooks).

Comment: Assuming you're using the `graphicx` package, you could load it with the `demo` option. That way, you can construct an MWE without having to post the pdf file you use to create the figure.

Comment: As I am unfamiliar with the \demo option, I have uploaded the PDF for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you replace the `picture` environment inside the `figure` environment with a couple of `subfigure` environments. (The `subfigure` environment is made available by loading the `subcaption` package.) That way, you can generate labels for each subfigure separately -- as well as for the figure as a whole -- letting you then cross-reference each of these entities individually. The command `\captionsetup` lets you customize virtually every aspect of the appearance of the captions, including their font size.

The following, modified form of your MWE shows how this might be done. It has three `\caption` and three `\label` directives, one each for the subfigures and the overall figure.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove demo option for real program
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.0in, bottom=1.2in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{size=footnotesize} % optional
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=ForestGreen, linkcolor=Red, urlcolor=Blue}

\begin{document}

Some text here to talk about the first part of the figure followed by a 
reference to Figure~\ref{fig:1a}. Some text here to talk about the second 
part of the figure followed by a reference to Figure~\ref{fig:1b}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % or whatever dimension is desired
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{spiral.eps}
\caption{Some text describing the first part.} 
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{redsquare.pdf}
\caption{Some text describing the second part.}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{The caption for Figure 1 goes here. Both parts of Figure 1 are described.} 
\label{Figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jordan -- Glad you found my answer useful. Incidentally, I've taken the liberty of editing the question's title as its subject is not so much `hyperref` but cross-referencing in general.